# Rails: Autofill a form field if a user clicks on URL link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get it so that when after sending someone an email, if they click on the link on the email to go to my rails form then something in the URL of that link will autofill a part of the form already for them.

I want something nice and simple. I thought it was something like localhost:3000/form_page?form_field=value but this doesn't seem to work. The page loads without issue but the field is still empty. Am I on the right track here or is something like this not possible?

More info:

In a form with id 'new_user' I have this field.

```
<div class="input email required user_email"><label class="email required control-label" for="user_email"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Email</label><input class="string email required" id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" value=""></div>
```

Comment: Could you add some view code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed on a good track, but you have to go a little bit further.

The form page is processed by an action of a specific controller, and on that action, you have access to a variable called `params`. In this variable, you can retrieve all the parameters of the request :)

For your example

```
class FormController < ApplicationController
  def form_action
    @form_value = params[:form_field]
  end
end
```

Like I have done above, you should pass the retrieved parameters to an instance variable in the action of the controller. This variable will then be accessible in your view !

ERB :

```
<%= @form_value %>
```

HAML:

```
= form_value
```

will display the result

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it, in your view as you posted it, add this change:

```
type="email" value="<%= params[:form_field] %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah thanks guys. I got it working now.

I put ?var=blah in the url then put the value of the field to be params[:var] and now it autofills.